# Alfa Romeo Mito - various issues and MOT advisories

Tags: troubleshooting

I have an Alfa Romeo Mito 1.4 Multi-Air (135bhp), the car has been parked up for year.

Fitted a new battery and started it ,  steering was very heavy so I checked the tyres. The ESP/power steering light was initially on but then went off and steering went extremely light.  Does this mean the ESP has failed or is this just a side-effect of the dead battery?

Something called a the "Poly-V" belt has snapped? What would this be and what is it used for?

There is also damage to the sills after I drove over a small island and impacted them - can these be replaced or renewed?

Last year's MOT came with an advisory for front brakes being imbalanced and that the system either needed readjusting or repairing (3.7.B.5B) - there is a grinding/scratching noise when braking, could this be related?

Another advisory states "OS Front Suspension corroded but not seriously weakened" what does this one mean?

Comment: Can you add some punctuation to your question.  It is very difficult to read and understand.

Comment: Capitalization as well, please.

Comment: Get it to a garage and have them do a complete list as the list from last year will have other items to be added to it.

Comment: @lisawill I've given your question an extensive edit as it wasn't particularly easy to read. Hopefully I've not changed your intent too much or got any of the details wrong!

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean the ESP has failed or is this just a side-effect of the dead battery?

Could be a side-effect of the dead battery - especially if the problem doesn't re-present when you restart the car.

> Something called a the "Poly-V" belt has snapped? What would this be and what is it used for?

The Poly-V belt most likely drives various ancillary components off the engine - not sure what on the Mito to be honest but could be things like A/C compressor, alternator etc. Potentially even the power steering pump - which might explain the issues you were having with the steering (although I wouldn't expect it to get *lighter* if the belt snapped!). Usually a poly-v belt snapping isn't a major job to do and it's unlikely to have done significant damage to anything.

> There is also damage to the sills after I drove over a small island and impacted them - can these be replaced or renewed?

Depends on what the damage is - if we're talking cosmetic damage to sills then this is something you can do things about. If it's more significant, structural damage (which is unlikely unless you were going at a significant speed) then it's a problem - sills can't easily be "replaced" as they make up part of the main chassis of the car. Essentially you need to cut our the affected sections and weld in replacements.

Like I say though this is unlikely - it's most likely just cosmetic damage. If there's sufficient damage to expose the bare metal beneath any paintwork though you'll want to address that sooner rather than later. The last thing you want is the sills rusting on you!

> Last year's MOT came with an advisory for front brakes being imbalanced and that the system either needed readjusting or repairing (3.7.B.5B) - there is a grinding/scratching noise when braking, could this be related?

This is probably your most urgent problem to address - if the balance was so far out that it barely passed that's not good. You're going to need a trusted garage to take the front brakes apart and have a look - it could be something as simple as just needing new discs and pads or it could be a sticking piston on one of the calipers. Brakes are an essential safety component and a substantial imbalance in the fronts could see the car's direction pulling significantly to one side under heavy braking - and depending on what side that is could see the car slewing into either on-coming traffic or some poor sod on the pavement.

> Another advisory states "OS Front Suspension corroded but not seriously weakened" what does this one mean?

It means basically what it says - the OS ("off-side" a.k.a. driver's side) front suspension has begun to corrode but that so far it's still doing the job sufficiently. Assuming this was on the previous MOT then it may have progressed since then - if it's corroded too much then it will need to be replaced.

Given there's a reasonable length list of various issues and you mention the car has been stood for a year I think the wisest course of action at this point is to take the car to a trusted garage/mechanic and have them assess what the car needs doing to be made roadworthy and go from there. Several of the things you mention relate directly to safety-critical stuff (suspension, steering, brakes) so they aren't things to ignore or take chances on.

Comment: MOT advisories can depend on the mood of the examiner, and whether the shop doing the MOT wants some more work. Three years ago I had an advisory about a corroded exhaust system. Two years and one year ago there was no advisory about the same thing, and the original exhaust is still there and working fine! I've also had advisories about the top layer of transparent plastic peeling from a number plate for more years than I can remember, and it's still legal!

Comment: @alephzero definitely! Corrosion ones in particular can be quite subjective. Brake balance ones *shouldn't* be as its measured and quantified. Not to say that some unscrupulous shops aren't above lying to get some more cash for work though. All the more reason to get a trusted mechanic to check things out

Comment: The Mito uses an electric power steering system, so not driven from the poly belt. Suspect it might be a bit sensitive to battery voltage.

Comment: @Kickstart Good shout! I hadn't realised the Mito was electric PAS.